# Python not catching exception

Tags: python

For some reason my code is not catching an exception when I throw it. I have

```
def trim_rad(rad):
    ...

    if not modrad.shape[0]:
        raise IndexError("Couldn't find main chunk")
    return modrad, thetas
```

Then later I call that function:

```
try:
    modrad, thetas = trim_rad(rad)
except IndexError("Couldn't find main chunk"):
    return 0
```

Yet I still get a traceback with that exception. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're only supposed to put the type name there, not an instance of the type. If you want to further narrow it down to handle only a special `IndexError` that you will be throwing and leave regular ole `IndexErrors` alone, create a narrower exception type that inherits from `IndexError` and raise/catch that.

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't TypeError. I thought I tried `except 1:` before and got a TypeError, but trying it now, it just passes through.

Comment: @user2357112 Evidently it does cause a TypeError in Python 3: http://ideone.com/yy4XAy. You're right though, it doesn't matter in 2.x

Comment: @Asad It's weird that there wasn't any warning that I was doing it wrong. So if I want to catch that specific error and not other `IndexErrors`, is it more standard to subclass `IndexError`, or parse the message and re-raise the error if it's not the specified message? I only use the error in this instance, would making a new subclass be a bit too heavy duty?

Comment: @ari It is better to subclass IndexErrors (IMO at least), but it is entirely up to you. Both approaches would work, although using string comparison for crucial decision making and control flow always feels gross to me. I'm no Python expert, so YMMV.

Comment: @ari It would have broken loudly if you were using Python 3 (see http://ideone.com/xUlGsy), but things are a bit looser in Python 2.

Comment: @Asad Is there any use to that aspect of 'looseness'? What's the purpose of letting people put something that's not an error after except?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You gave `except` an instance of an `IndexError`.  Do this instead:

```
try:
    modrad, thetas = trim_rad(rad)
except IndexError:
    print "Couldn't find main chunk"
    return 0
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> try:
...     [1][1]
... except IndexError('no'):
...     pass
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> try:
...     [1][1]
... except IndexError:
...     pass
...
>>>
```

Answer (score 13):

Catch just the `IndexError`.

```
try:
    raise IndexError('abc')
except IndexError('abc'):
    print 'a'



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 2, in <module>
    raise IndexError('abc')
IndexError: abc

try:
    raise IndexError('abc')
except IndexError:
    print 'a'


a # Output
```

**So, reduce your code to**

```
try:
    modrad, thetas = trim_rad(rad)
except IndexError:
    return 0
```

If you want to catch the error message too, use the following syntax:

```
try:
    raise IndexError('abc')
except IndexError as err:
    print err


abc
```

Answer (score 3):

change

```
except IndexError("Couldn't find main chunk"):
```

to

```
except IndexError:
```

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be catching the exception wrong.  You catch exceptions of type, the notation below will assign the exception to e so you can read the description in your except handler.

```
try:
    modrad, thetas = trim_rad(rad)
except IndexError as e:
    print e.message
    return 0
```